# "git push" works, but "@{push}" gives the error "cannot resolve"

Tags: git

I'm trying to use the `@{push}` notation. I have `branch.<branchname>.pushRemote` set. If I use `git push -v`, it correctly works, and prints:

```
Pushing to git@github.com:<my-repo>
```

However, if I try to use `git diff @{push}` I get the error:

> fatal: cannot resolve 'simple' push to a single destination

As far as I understand, this should work, according to the manual:

```
[<branchname>]@{push}, e.g. master@{push}, @{push}
       The suffix @{push} reports the branch "where we would push to" if git push were run 
       while branchname was checked out (or the current HEAD if no branchname is specified).
```

`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{push}` prints the same "cannot resolve" error message.

Is this a git bug, or did I setup something incorrectly? Any tips what to try?

Comment: For `@{push}` to work, your Git has to be able to resolve everything on its own. It seems like there *is* enough information in your repository and configuration for Git to do this and therefore this should probably work and this is probably a bug. Get the most current Git (which has bug-reporting tools built in, finally), set up a reproducer that reproduces it, and report a bug. If you can't make a reproducer, perhaps the bug is already fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a different upstream branch name set via `branch.<name>.merge`, then you'll need to set `push.default` to `current` instead of the default `simple`.

I think this issue arises from the default value of the git config `push.default`, which is `simple`.

> `current` - push the current branch to update a branch with the same
> name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central
> workflows.
>
> ...
>
> `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like `upstream` with an added
> safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different
> from the local one.
>
> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you
> normally pull from, work as `current`. This is the safest option and is
> suited for beginners.
>
> This mode has become the default in Git 2.0.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault

With the default `push.default` value of `simple`:

```
$ git diff @{push}..HEAD
fatal: cannot resolve 'simple' push to a single destination

$ git push -n
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use
        
    git push origin HEAD:master
        
To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
        
    git push origin HEAD
        
To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

With `push.default` set to `current`, `git diff @{push}..HEAD` and `git push -n` work.

Comment: Thank you, setting `push.default` to `current` solves the case. But then I don't understand why `git push` works. `git push` happily pushes with `push.default` being `simple`.

Comment: If an unqualified `git push` works, then I think the `@{push}` shorthand should also work.  If you have a case where that is not true, it might be a git bug, but I would be interested to see some simple reproduction steps.